# Twitter login in iOS6

Tags: ios6

I am working with twitter integration in my application. I am using Twitter.framework,Social.Framework

Now my requirement is i need to do twitter login with my app not from setting,

From my app user can login or he can register to twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to go through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6).

I guarantee it will take you at most 1 hour to get your hands on the Twitter framework and to have a decent result in your app. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful https://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine

It worked for me.
Just follow those steps.